# How to get TinyMce content in IE 8 or 9

Tags: forms, post, tinymce, submit

I have a tinyMce box in my form and submitting this form using jquery ajax.

```
    var myDecription=tinyMCE.get('myDescription').getContent();
var descriptionOptions ={beforeSubmit: showDescRequest,success:  
        showDescResponse}; 
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(descriptionOptions);
```

When i am submitting this form using above code in all other browsers except IE 8 or 9 the data is successfuly saved in db but in IE the data is not saved successfully. I am using post method to save the data but using post method the tinyMce content is not got in Internet explorer. Please help me.

Comment: actually the above code is only for validating the form using jquery. the actual form is posted by post method and action file. but in post method the tinymce data is not got. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to call `tinymce.triggerSave()` beforeSubmit. This should work on IE8 and IE9 too.